# debug anonymous function in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, coffeescript

I'm building a prototype web application and I want to integrate it in chrome web pages (not necessary for production).
So I have a build a backend solution to send all my js file into one request and send the result to the chrome extension client for organisation and ease purpose.

myBackend.coffee (my own nodejs server)

```
getScript = (name) ->
  filename = "#{__dirname}/../public/js/#{name}.js"
  fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8')

get '/chrome/includes', (req, res) ->
  scripts = [
    getScript 'vendor/jquery'
    getScript 'vendor/jquery.ui'
    getScript 'vendor/mousetrap'
    getScript 'vendor/mustache'
    getScript 'vendor/backbone'
    #...
    getScript 'main-chrome'
  ]

  res.send
    scripts: scripts
    css: [
      #...
    ]
```

backckground.coffee (chrome client)

```
$.ajax
  url: "http://localhost:3001/chrome/includes"

  success: (data) ->
    compactedCode = ''
    _.each data.scripts, (code) ->
      compactedCode += code

    chrome.tabs.executeScript tab.id, code: compactedCode
```

Ok, so that's good, but the problem appear when I do wrong code in "compatedCode".

Chrome tell me:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>   (anonymous function)
>   But not telling me where is the error.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6tc60GuFE4WSk4zTXhzV1luOE0/edit?usp=sharing

I have a lot of code so this is not really an option to write "debugger" everywhere.

What should I do to debug in proficient way?

Comment: Can you try a `try {} catch(e) {}` block?

Comment: Comment out the `getScript` lines if you can, to see what file it's in, as a start.

Comment: Yes, already commented some scripts, but this is very very painful to debug because, multiples files have this same "generic" error.
All of the "compactedCode" executed work well in standar web page.

Comment: `try {} catch(e) {}` doesn't work well in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a great solution here:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=95352

Just need to add this, wonderful

```
compactedCode += "\n//@ sourceURL=foo.js"
```